# Opacity on Control

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to make a control semi-transparent?

Comment: Do you mean "to change the opacity of a control" or "to make a control opaque" or something else entirely?

Comment: Which control, where why how. Transparency doesn't really works for winforms so my suggestion would be using a diffent technique all together.

Answer (score 4):

The direct answer to your question is 'No'.

WinForms supports Translucency at the Form level ([Form.Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx)), but not controls.  In cases this was important, I have used layered forms.

If this feature is important and changing frameworks is an option, WPF does support translucent controls.

Answer (score 2):

**If** the control supports transparent backgrounds, you can use `Color.FromArgb()` to set a translucent color:

```
button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
```

Depending on how you want this to work, you would vary the alpha value (to between 0 and 255).

Comment: But this will only make the background-color transparent and the controls behind will not be visible.

Comment: True that any controls behind the "transparent" control will not be visible, but that is not made clear by the question, it was "Is it possible to make a control semi-transparent?" which was answered... If more detailed answer is required then I think we need a more detailed question.

Comment: From my point of view it wasnt as the control itself ISNT transparent in any way as Codler said. If I get this right this will only change the opacity of the background color so the default color is getting more visible. Useless thing for me then. You could in that case just pick a more gray-like color for your background. Same result.