# How would I make a label or a picture box less opaque?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, game-development

I'm making a game where a player has limited visibility, and this visibility can be changed throughout the game using powerups and checkpoints. Since I don't know how I'd actually do visibility the right way, I decided on putting a label/picturebox over the player and using that as the visibility limiter. My problem is, I don't know how I could make a picture box or label less opaque than another on the same form?

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that this is a Windows Forms application?

Comment: SO explicitly requires only one topic per question. If you have two issues, you need to post two separate questions. You need to edit this question and remove the second paragraph, then post that as a separate question. This is an example of why you should have taken the site tour when prompted.

Comment: Yes sorry its a windows forms application, and I just edited it. My bad, had no idea

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064774/opacity-on-control

Comment: will this work in vb.net?

Comment: There is no real transparency in Windows Forms. What you can do is provide virtual transparency by forcing a control to display what its parent is displaying behind it as its own background. The problem with that is that it will only show the parent, so if there's a sibling control behind the "transparent" it will not show through. The solution here is probably to create a `Label` with a transparent `BackColor`, make it the same size as the `PictureBox` and then make the `PictureBox` its parent. I think that should produce the effect you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a solution to your general issue. Create a new Windows Forms Application project and add two `PictureBox` controls and two `Label` controls to the form. Set an `Image` in each of the `PictureBox` controls. Add the following code to the form:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With Label1
        .AutoSize = False
        .Size = PictureBox1.Size
        .Location = Point.Empty
        .Parent = PictureBox1
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100)
    End With

    With Label2
        .AutoSize = False
        .Size = PictureBox2.Size
        .Location = Point.Empty
        .Parent = PictureBox2
        .BackColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100, 100)
    End With
End Sub
```

Run the project and you will see that the two `PictureBox` controls are overlayed with the `Label` controls. The first `PictureBox` is completely obscured by the corresponding `Label` because the `Label` is opaque, while the second `PictureBox` shows through the second `Label` because of the transparent `BackColor` of that `Label`.

In your case, because the `Label` is parented by the `PictureBox`, you can still just move the `PictureBox` around as normal and the transparent `Label` will move with it. Note that you cannot add child controls to a `PictureBox` in the designer, so you have to do it in code as I have done above.

EDIT:

I won't do it here but it's worth noting that you could actually create your own custom control that inherited `PictureBox` and then created its own child `Label` in the constructor(s). You could then expose `BackColor` of the `Label` via a property of the control and you could then set the colour and transparency level of that overlay via that property. You might choose to expose the transparency level separately or just use the alpha channel of that `Color` property.

EDIT:

I said I wouldn't do it here but here is an implementation of the custom control I mentioned above:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

''' <summary>
''' A picture box control with a transparent overlay.
''' </summary>
Public Class OverlaidPictureBox
    Inherits PictureBox

    'The label that provides the overlay.
    Private WithEvents overlayLabel As Label

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="OverlaidPictureBox"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks>
    ''' The overlay color is the default back color but fully transparent.
    ''' </remarks>
    Public Sub New()
        Me.New(Color.FromArgb(0, DefaultBackColor.R, DefaultBackColor.G, DefaultBackColor.B))
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new instance of the <see cref="OverlaidPictureBox"/> class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="overlayColor">
    ''' The overlay color, including the transparency level.
    ''' </param>
    Public Sub New(overlayColor As Color)
        overlayLabel = New Label With {.BackColor = overlayColor, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}

        Controls.Add(overlayLabel)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The overlay color, including the transparency level.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' A <see cref="Color"/> value representing the overlay color.
    ''' </returns>
    <Category("Appearance")>
    Public Property OverlayColor As Color
        Get
            Return overlayLabel.BackColor
        End Get
        Set
            overlayLabel.BackColor = Value
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when the value of the <see cref="OverlayColor"/> property changes.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event OverlayColorChanged As EventHandler

    Private Sub overlayLabel_BackColorChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles overlayLabel.BackColorChanged
        OnOverlayColorChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Raises the <see cref="OverlayColorChanged"/> event.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="e">
    ''' The data fr the event.
    ''' </param>
    Protected Overridable Sub OnOverlayColorChanged(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent OverlayColorChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Just add that class to your project and build and then the new control will appear in the *Toolbox* and you can use it like any other control. It will behave like any other `PictureBox` by default, but you will see a new `OverlayColor` property in the *Properties* window. That should be (0, 240, 240, 240) by default. You can change the leading 0 to any other value up to 255 and you'll see the overlay get more opaque. You can also change the other values if you want the overlay to be other than the default `Control` color.

Answer (score 0):

Although the method to do such a thing varies from game engine & language, here are a few methods that could work for you.

Overlay a "vignette image" over the player's screen. One such image could be this: [vignette image - click me](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/uploads/monthly_2020_04/595FAD8C-E33F-4E12-A974-9B2D043A2BA3.png.eac9bd8cac80378692e4115553790af8.png) This image, for a power-up feature, could be replaced with one with slightly less "darkness" (for lack of a better word), in order to increase the viewing area. Sizing up (increasing the width and height of an image, and adjusting the x and y coordinates to keep it in the middle) works as well.

In Unreal Engine, I believe there is an editable property in the software. For more, here is Unreal Engine's documentation on vignette systems: [unreal engine's documentation - click me](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/PostProcessEffects/Vignette/index.html)

Unity also has a vignette feature. Here it is in the UI: [image: unity vignette feature]

If you need more help (regarding the Unity method), here is a resource worth checking out: [jimmy vegas' unity vignette tutorial - click me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuvx9tWGlHc)

Let me know if any of these work. I'm not sure how you were making your game, so my response may or may not work in your specific case.

Comment: no this is in visual basic as a windows form app, not through an actual game engine. Thank you a bunch though :D

Comment: That's too bad, I'm not familiar with that. If I find anything, I'll be sure to share!